# Can a SD file format be opened in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, file-formats

I downliaded a SD file from here: http://portal.emodnet-hydrography.eu/geographic-grid
How can I open it in QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

Why not download the GeoTiff format? That can easily be opened by QGIS.

If depth is required then why not use the .asc format? That can easily be opened in QGIS:

[image]

Colour image of the .asc file for clarity:

[image]

Comment: Fledermaus file format is probably more feature rich for that kind of data.

Comment: Fledermaus is SD?

Comment: In the portal there is a button Help which shows `SD files:
The SD files can be viewed in the QPS 3D Fledermaus application or in the iView4D viewer, which is available as a free download` Link is broken but you can find more information from http://www.qps.nl/display/main/home.

Comment: @vesanto, the Tiff has no depth (Z) values and i was hoping the SD has.

Comment: You could use the .asc file, which can be directly opened by QGIS and has the depth.

Comment: The netcdf file also has the depth as a subdataset. You have to use `gdal_translate -a_ullr` to get the picture in the right place.